# Login loop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after last updates

Tags: 14.04, networking, login

After the last Ubuntu 14.04 LTS update, the login was looping a guest account requiring a password though none was created. Someone solved this by creating the 50-no-guest.conf. But now, though my passwords are good, it is still looping when i enter the root or user login. I deleted .Xauthority & .ICEauthority, created a newuser, still the same.

Also, i can't connect to the internet as the networking has not been started.

I have been stuck for 5 days now and i am quite discouraged as i can't get any work done on this OS. Please help!

Comment: did you try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634

Comment: yes, thank you. many good info there. i tried everything there except statements that require that i be online and my login is still looping...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, which is now solved thanks to bits of other posts and pages.
I think that with the step 4 alone, it should be enough to fix it.

1. Found in problem#289482 : "Seperate your login issues from X issues. First try logging in to a VTY. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 and login. Once logged in try running 
   sudo X :2 & 
   you should be taken to a black screen with a X for a mouse pointer.
   ***I was not.***
2. Found an error in the file .xsession-error : 
   X error 155 (GLX) 19 (X_GLXQueryServerString).
3. Found this in ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249830 : "Did you have the restricted AMD drivers installed?" 
   ***I had.***
4. Found this on help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver : 
   Removing the proprietary fglrx driver. If you've previously installed the ATI binary/proprietary driver (a.k.a Catalyst/fglrx), you need to make sure it's fully purged before trying to use the open-source ati/radeon driver. 
   sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
5. on the same page : "No configuration is necessary for ATI driver in the modern versions of Ubuntu." 
   ***I just rebooted ... it was fixed !***
6. If you want to reinstall fglrx, see 
   help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD?action=show&redirect=BinaryDriverHowto%2FATI
7. And I just found the explanation : askubuntu.com/questions/595359/fglrx-wont-install-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/599262#599262

BB

Comment: Hi,

Here is what i tried:
I accessed the Ubuntu partition from another linux distro (puppytahr as root)

Items 1-2) the xsession-errors was empty
Item 3) i don't recall what the restricted AMD drivers are... can you specify please?
Item 4-7) i don't have the ATI graphic board. I have the Intel one though.

Thanx for replying